# Custom instagram login view

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram, instagram-api

I am building an app that requires signing up with Instagram. I can use the traditional web view for the user to enter their login information but I find it ugly.

I want to have custom text fields with a custom login button. How can I achieve this?

I don't see a login endpoint in the developer documentation on Instagram.

Much appreciated.

Comment: use authentication api and get an access token. Please read documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a webview to open Instagram's login page and do authentication.

Custom login page is not possible since instagram only supports Oauth2 `Authorization Code` and `Implicit Grant`, so u have to open Instagram login page in webview